# Javascript alert not working on button click

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I have typed in the javascript just as you have but on a separate file linked through the HTML file. The button shows up however I am not getting any alert when it is clicked. My code is as follows:

Javascript(index.js):

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript is Fun!(When it works)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myButton">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know why my button is not working? It seems to me all my code is in order unless I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is being executed prior to the element it refers to existing in the page. Move the JavaScript to the end of the document or wrap it in a window.onload function.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        alert("Hi");
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kays1y9j/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the document to be constructed before you can reference elements in it.

Put your script tag in `body`, just before the end. This will ensure that the document is there when the script runs.

Or, you can wrap your js in a load listener like this

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  //...your stuff here
})
```

Comment: Have my vote for making the code easier to coexist with. (`addEventListener` adds an event listener on top of any previously set ones, whereas `.onload` cancels any previously set `onload` event.). Here is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/v6ao73ap/

Comment: Thanks @blex! Definitely a much more sustainable approach to event handling!

Answer (score 0):

You should not put `<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>`
 before `<body></body>`, because when the browser is trying to register the event, the `<button>` is not loaded already. So when you take a look at the control panel, you would get something like `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.

The right version might be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript is Fun!(When it works)</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myButton">Click</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you should put `script` code below the `button`

```
<button id="myButton">Click</button>

document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing is you haven't included jquery in your code, change your HTML to this

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript is Fun!(When it works)</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myButton">Click</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

and your index.js to

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        alert("Hi");
    });
    });
```

this worked for me hope this work for you too